# React Native Vs React Js programming language

Tags: reactjs, react-native

which programming language is for reactjs and react native ? I have knowledge web application. If I learn react native , Is it same programming structure and architecture reactjs also.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the two are very similar in many ways and the difference is in the environment.

React uses a technology called `JSX` which lets you use HTML elements in JavaScript. On the other hand, React Native lets you use a set of components defined by itself to use in JavaScript and while compiling to production for IOS or Android it converts those components to native components of those OSes. There is a lot more difference in how the packages work and how to use the os but if you are a web developer learning React Native and then taking a crash course on React will not be a big challenge for you. But the route that most of the developers take is that they first mature React.js and later move on to React Native and that's the same path that I took and I believe this way helps you more as most of the courses on React Native will not go deep in React.js.

Take a look at the example below. It is a React.js component that returns a hello and an input for a name.

```js
const App = () => {
    const [name, setName] = useState('');

    const onChange = (event) => {
        setName(event.target.value);
    };
    
    return (
        <div>
            <div>Hello {name}</div>
            <input placeholder="Name" value={name} onChange={onChange}/>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Settings up a React Native app might take a little bit more time and effort but here's the same part of the code in React Native:

```js
import { TextInput, Text, View } from "react-native";

const App = () => {
    const [name, setName] = useState('');

    const onChangeText = (text) => {
        setName(text);
    };
    
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>Hello {name}</Text>
            {/* you can also just pass setName as the value of onChangeText */}
            <TextInput placeholder="Name" value={name} onChangeText={onChangeText}/>
        </View>
    );
};
```

The big difference comes in styling. In your normal web app with React.js, you can just create a CSS file set a class name and import the style file in your JavaScript code to set styles for your app, Like below:

`style.css` file:

```css
.message {
    color: blue;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.input {
    width: 300px;
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

`App.js` file:

```js
import './style.css';

const App = () => {
    const [name, setName] = useState('');

    const onChange = (event) => {
        setName(event.target.value);
    };
    
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="message">Hello {name}</div>
            <input className="input" placeholder="Name" value={name} onChange={onChange}/>
        </div>
    );
};
```

While in React Native you can not use CSS and instead you need to use a styling method much more restricted provided by React Native(It is essentially the same as inline-styling):

```js
import { TextInput, Text, View, StyleSheet } from "react-native";

const App = () => {
    const [name, setName] = useState('');

    const onChangeText = (text) => {
        setName(text);
    };
    
    return (
        <View>
            <Text style={styles.message}>Hello {name}</Text>
            {/* you can also just pass setName as the value of onChangeText */}
            <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder="Name" value={name} onChangeText={onChangeText}/>
        </View>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    input: {
        height: 40,
        margin: 12,
        borderWidth: 1,
        padding: 10,
    },
    message: {
        color: 'blue',
        fontSize: 20,
    },
});
```